# will jhipster auto refresh data, when i update db manually?

Tags: jhipster

i'm on my first jhipster project. I had updated the record(role of user) in db manually. but i can't see any change in gateway. will jhipster auto refresh data?
or is there any way to refresh db?

1. create jhipster microservices project uaa gateway
2. INSERT into jhi_authority (name) VALUES('ROLE_TEST')
3. INSERT into jhi_user_authority  (user_id, authority_name) VALUES('1', 'ROLE_TEST' )
4. i can't find change in gateway: adminnistration-user management

Comment: Care to elaborate more?

Comment: 1. create jhipster microservices project uaa gateway
2. INSERT into jhi_authority (name) VALUES('ROLE_TEST') 
3. INSERT into jhi_user_authority  (user_id, authority_name) VALUES('1', 'ROLE_TEST' ) 
4. i can't find change in gateway: adminnistration-user management

Comment: Which db? How did you run your SQL inserts?

Comment: mysql, run sql insert in navicat manually.